# SVNKit library used for internal project?

Tags: svn, licensing, svnkit, svn-api

Can SVNKit library be used for an application that is going to be used and redistributed only inside the company I work for? Does it count as a commercial use?

http://svnkit.com/licensing.html

Thanks.

Comment: You should ask SVNKit developers. Try the support@svnkit.com and the mailing list: http://svnkit.com/support.html#mailing-lists

Comment: I sent the following e-mail to SVNKit support: `I’m trying to interpret the Open Source SVNKit license.  Is it permitted to use the product for an internal company tool without the requirement to make the source code available outside of the company?  The tool would NOT be distributed to more than a small handful of people inside of the organization.` and received the response: `Yes, in this case you may use SVNKit for free under the terms of TMate Open Source license.`

Answer (score 1):

The [SVNKit license](http://svnkit.com/license.html) clearly says you **can't** use it in your case:

```
Redistributions in any form must be accompanied by information on how to 
obtain complete source code for the software that uses SVNKit and any 
accompanying software that uses the software that uses SVNKit. The source 
code must either be included in the distribution or be available for no 
more than the cost of distribution plus a nominal fee, and must be freely 
redistributable under reasonable conditions. For an executable file, complete 
source code means the source code for all modules it contains. It does not 
include source code for modules or files that typically accompany the major 
components of the operating system on which the executable file runs.
```

however you may opt to:

```
Redistribution in any form without redistributing source code for software 
that uses SVNKit is possible only when such redistribution is explictly permitted 
by TMate Software. Please, contact TMate Software at support@svnkit.com to 
get such permission.
```

Comment: It is not so clear for me.

"Redistributions in any form must be accompanied by information on how to obtain complete source code for the software that uses SVNKit and any accompanying software that uses the software that uses SVNKit."

Application will be redistributed with information how to obtain complete source code and every person using it will have access to source code. Also it will be free. Doesn't that meet license conditions?

Comment: Will I, mstrap, get the source code, too?

Comment: If you will be the one of those who gets the application then yes, source code will be available for you.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the intention of the license is to be similar to GPL, but with a commercial addition. But I agree with @bahrep now, that it's best to contact support@svnkit.com and ask them. If the free license works for your scenario, it's certainly a good idea to have a positive answer directly from the licensors.